# Force view to reload tvml content on Apple TV/tvos

Tags: javascript, tvos, apple-tv, tvml

I have been working on dynamically generating tvml-templates with very frequently changing content for a tvOS app on Apple TV. Generating the templates works fine, however I have not been able to get the app to update/reload the content of a template when navigating back and forth between views or leaving and reentering the app. Only rebooting seems to reload the tvml template.

Answer (score 2):

Your template will refresh itself automatically whenever you manipulate the TVML within the template document.

If you maintain a reference to the document like so:

```
var myDoc;

resourceLoader.loadResource(templateURL,
   function(resource) {
     if (resource) {
       myDoc = self.makeDocument(resource);
     });
   }
```

you can manipulate the TVML using **myDoc** and your view will automatically change.

So if your template document includes a "collectionList" and you were to run this code:

```
//Removes the child elements of the first collectionList
var collectionLists = myDoc.getElementsByTagName("collectionList");
var collectionList = collectionLists.item(0);
while (collectionList.firstChild) {
   collectionList.removeChild(collectionList.firstChild);
}
```

your view would no longer display the UI elements within the collectionList.  The view will refresh itself the moment the code is run.

Comment: get Client server sample app in Swift2 @ https://github.com/phanisai4u/sampleAppsSwift/tree/master/TvOSClientServerBasisSample/TestTvOS

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @shirefriendship pointed my in the right direction (thank you!). As another example, if you wanted to change the text of a single element in a template (such as the description), you would need to use the `innerHTML` property:

```
function changeDescription(incomingString) {
    console.log("inside the change description function")
    if (incomingString) {
        var theDescription = myDoc.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0);
        theDescription.innerHTML = incomingString;
    }
}
```

This changes the description immediately to the viewer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [atvjs](https://github.com/emadalam/atvjs) framework, you can easily create and navigate to dynamic pages which are regenerated while navigating.

```
ATV.Page.create({
    name: 'home',
    url: 'path/to/your/api/that/returns/json',
    template: your_template_function
});
// navigate to your page
ATV.Navigation.navigate('home');
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this in the header of your API:

> Cache-Control:no-cache

Got it from Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/YourFirstAppleTVApp.html

> IMPORTANT
>
> When serving JavaScript and XML files from your web server, you often
>   need to ensure that any changes to your pages are always visible to
>   the client app. To do this, your server must ensure that the client
>   does not cache any of the pages. When your server responds to an HTTP
>   request for a page that should not be cached, the server should
>   include Cache-Control:no-cache in the HTTP response header.