# TVML Add items dynamically?

Tags: tvos, tvml

I have seen this question ([Force view to reload tvml content on Apple TV/tvos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33532217/force-view-to-reload-tvml-content-on-apple-tv-tvos)) and the answer describes how you could remove things from the DOM but is there any way to add them?

I know about the standard appendChild on a NodeList but how would you create the proper element to be appended?  That is, when you create a document in TVML it is a special XML syntax that is then parsed into a document.  Is there a way to parse just a portion of a document so that you can then add it into, say a section within a shelf to dynamically add more items to the row after the document has been presented?

P.S.  I've tried using Presenter.parser.parseFromString() with the xml for the new item but it is throwing a IKDOMException with that syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many approaches you can take to accomplish adding items dynamically.  An important thing to note is that Apple's sample code is NOT structured for dynamic data very well.

After you create a template, you can change the document in a variety of ways.  You should have ownership of the document after the template is created. In the following example, the variable **doc** contains a Stack Template document I'd like to manipulate.

```
  var shelves = doc.getElementsByTagName("shelf"); //get all the shelves
  var shelfToAddTo = shelves.item(0); //choose the index for the shelf you want to add to.
  var sectionToAdd = `<section>
            <lockup>
            <img src="pathToImg" width="100" height="100"/>
            <title>Title Goes Here</title>
            </lockup> 
            </section>`;
  shelfToAddTo.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', sectionToAdd); //this will add the new section before the </shelf> tag.
```

This will add a new section and lockup to the first shelf in your document.

Comment: Thanks very much.  It was the fact that I could use the raw html with insertAdjacentHTML() that I was missing.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE:**

You can use DataItem API to manage your data with prototypes.

> You can’t bind JSON objects directly to a template, you have to turn them into DataItem objects. Retrieve the desired section element and create a new data item for the section. Create new data items from the JSON objects. The setPropertyPath method is used bind the new data items to the section data item. Listing 5-4 shows a modified parseJson function that takes the information from the Images.json file, turns them into data items, and binds them to the appropriate section.
>
> Using the prototype element, you can create a single lockup that contains like objects. Inside of the lockup, you define the structure of the lockup. Listing 5-5 shows a lockup that displays the objects defined as artwork in the type element. The URL and title for each image are pulled from the JSON object.

```
<prototypes>
    <lockup prototype="artwork">
        <img binding="@src:{url};" width="200" height="300"/>
        <title binding="textContent:{title};" />
    </lockup>
</prototypes>
<section binding="items:{images};" />
```

The following iterate and populate your prototype code using `items` from `section`:

```
function parseJson(information) {
    var results = JSON.parse(information);
    let parsedTemplate = templateDocument()
    navigationDocument.pushDocument(parsedTemplate)

    let shelf = parsedTemplate.getElementsByTagName("shelf").item(0)
    let section = shelf.getElementsByTagName("section").item(0)

    //create an empty data item for the section
    section.dataItem = new DataItem()

    //create data items from objects
    let newItems = results.map((result) => {
        let objectItem = new DataItem(result.type, result.ID);
        objectItem.url = result.url;
        objectItem.title = result.title;
        return objectItem;
    });

    //add the data items to the section's data item; 'images' relates to the binding name in the protoype where items:{images} is all of the newItems being added to the sections' data item;
    section.dataItem.setPropertyPath("images", newItems)
}
```

Template:

```
<document>
    <stackTemplate>
        <banner>
            <title>JSON Shelf</title>
        </banner>
        <collectionList>
            <shelf>
                <prototypes>
                    <lockup prototype="artwork">
                        <img binding="@src:{url};" width="200" height="300"/>
                        <title binding="textContent:{title};" />
                    </lockup>
                </prototypes>
                <section binding="items:{images};" />
            </shelf>
        </collectionList>
    </stackTemplate>
</document>
```

Reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TVMLKitJS/Conceptual/TVMLProgrammingGuide/GeneratingContentForYourApp.html

Hope it helps you.